# openflow switch sofeware implemented by Java

Tags: controller, emulation, openflow, sdn

I want to find an openflow switch emmulator software written by Java, but I can not get it through Google. And from standford's [webpage](http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/of-sw.html)  , I realize there is no such open source project, am I right?
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a switch emulator.

OpenflowJ is an implementation of low-level OpenFlow packet marshalling/unmarshalling and IO operations.
It is a new OpenFlow API for the controller stack

Refer: http://www.openflow.org.

Comment: But it is just a stack, and I cannot find switch demo in its source codes. Could you find such demo ? Thx!

Comment: This is not a switch model/module, why java based needed ?